# Winforms - Issue creating dynamic tables

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application where I have a views with multiple tables.  The tables get built dynamically by setting the name of their columns by the properties of the object, and then adding them to the dataset.  There's also an empty row added for each table. The issue I'm having is that out of the 9 objects being used to create these tables, 2 of the tables aren't getting any columns set or an empty row.

I've looked at the debug and have compared the objects properties that are getting columns to the one's without, and cannot decipher what the issue is.  Has anyone ever had this issue before? And if so, what was the problem?

Here's my code, let me know if there's any other information needed:

```
protected override DataSet GetDefaultFilterTypes()
    {
        return DataSetUtility.ToDataSet(new List<Type> { typeof(Counterparty), typeof(Address), typeof(Contact),
            typeof(Customer), typeof(Broker), typeof(ExchangeBroker), typeof(ExchangeBrokerAccount), typeof(Supplier), typeof(SupplierTerminalPriceMapping) });
    }


public static DataSet ToDataSet(IList<Type> list)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        foreach (Type item in list)
        {
            DataTable ta = new DataTable(item.ToString());
            ds.Tables.Add(ta);

            //add a column to table for each public property on T
            foreach (var propInfo in item.GetProperties())
            {
                Type colType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propInfo.PropertyType) ?? propInfo.PropertyType;
                ta.Columns.Add(propInfo.Name, colType);
            }

            DataRow row = ta.NewRow();

            foreach (var propInfo in item.GetProperties())
            {
                row[propInfo.Name] = DBNull.Value;
            }

            ta.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

Here's the class definitions for ExchangeBroker and Supplier - the objects not getting columns:

```
public partial class Supplier : MomentumEntityBase
{
    #region *** Properties

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    [Key,Required]
    [GreaterThanZero]
    public int SupplierId
    {
        get { return _supplierId; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _supplierId)) return;
            _supplierId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SupplierId");
        }
    }
    private int _supplierId;


    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false),StringLength(64)]
    public string CreationName
    {
        get { return _creationName; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _creationName)) return;
            _creationName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreationName");
        }
    }
    private string _creationName;


    [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _creationDate)) return;
            _creationDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreationDate");
        }
    }
    private DateTime _creationDate;


    [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = false)]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string RevisionName
    {
        get { return _revisionName; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _revisionName)) return;
            _revisionName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RevisionName");
        }
    }
    private string _revisionName;


    [DataMember(Order = 5, IsRequired = false)]

    public DateTime? RevisionDate
    {
        get { return _revisionDate; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _revisionDate)) return;
            _revisionDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RevisionDate");
        }
    }
    private DateTime? _revisionDate;


    #endregion

    #region *** Reverse Navigation

    #endregion

    #region *** Foreign Keys

    // Foreign keys
    public Counterparty Counterparty
    {
        get { return _counterparty; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _counterparty)) return;
            _counterparty = value;
            CounterpartyChangeTracker = _counterparty == null ? null : new ChangeTrackingCollection<Counterparty> { _counterparty };
             NotifyPropertyChanged("Counterparty");
        }
    }
    private Counterparty _counterparty;
    private ChangeTrackingCollection<Counterparty> CounterpartyChangeTracker { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region *** CTOR / Initialize

    public Supplier()
    {
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();

    #endregion

    #region *** Error

    public override string Error
    {
        get
        {
            var error = new StringBuilder();

            if (TrackingState != TrackableEntities.TrackingState.Deleted)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Error))
                {
                    error.AppendLine(base.Error);
                }

            }

            return error.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}


 [DataContract] 
public enum ExchangeBrokerColumns
{
    [EnumMember]
    ExchangeBrokerId = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    CreationName = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    CreationDate = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    RevisionName = 3,
    [EnumMember]
    RevisionDate = 4
}


// ExchangeBroker
//[DataContract]
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("EF.Reverse.POCO.Generator", "2.17.1.0")]
public partial class ExchangeBroker : MomentumEntityBase
{
    #region *** Properties

    [DataMember(Order = 1, IsRequired = true)]
    [Key,Required]
    [GreaterThanZero]
    public int ExchangeBrokerId
    {
        get { return _exchangeBrokerId; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _exchangeBrokerId)) return;
            _exchangeBrokerId = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ExchangeBrokerId");
        }
    }
    private int _exchangeBrokerId;


    [DataMember(Order = 2, IsRequired = true)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false),StringLength(64)]
    public string CreationName
    {
        get { return _creationName; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _creationName)) return;
            _creationName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreationName");
        }
    }
    private string _creationName;


    [DataMember(Order = 3, IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _creationDate)) return;
            _creationDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CreationDate");
        }
    }
    private DateTime _creationDate;


    [DataMember(Order = 4, IsRequired = false)]
    [StringLength(64)]
    public string RevisionName
    {
        get { return _revisionName; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _revisionName)) return;
            _revisionName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RevisionName");
        }
    }
    private string _revisionName;


    [DataMember(Order = 5, IsRequired = false)]

    public DateTime? RevisionDate
    {
        get { return _revisionDate; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _revisionDate)) return;
            _revisionDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RevisionDate");
        }
    }
    private DateTime? _revisionDate;


    #endregion

    #region *** Reverse Navigation

    // Reverse navigation
    public ChangeTrackingCollection<ExchangeBrokerAccount> ExchangeBrokerAccounts
    {
        get { return _exchangeBrokerAccounts; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _exchangeBrokerAccounts)) return;
            _exchangeBrokerAccounts = value;
             //NotifyPropertyChanged("ExchangeBrokerAccounts");
        }
    }
    private ChangeTrackingCollection<ExchangeBrokerAccount> _exchangeBrokerAccounts;

    #endregion

    #region *** Foreign Keys

    // Foreign keys
    public Counterparty Counterparty
    {
        get { return _counterparty; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _counterparty)) return;
            _counterparty = value;
            CounterpartyChangeTracker = _counterparty == null ? null : new ChangeTrackingCollection<Counterparty> { _counterparty };
             NotifyPropertyChanged("Counterparty");
        }
    }
    private Counterparty _counterparty;
    private ChangeTrackingCollection<Counterparty> CounterpartyChangeTracker { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region *** CTOR / Initialize

    public ExchangeBroker()
    {
        ExchangeBrokerAccounts = new ChangeTrackingCollection<ExchangeBrokerAccount>();
        InitializePartial();
    }

    partial void InitializePartial();

    #endregion

    #region *** Error

    public override string Error
    {
        get
        {
            var error = new StringBuilder();

            if (TrackingState != TrackableEntities.TrackingState.Deleted)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Error))
                {
                    error.AppendLine(base.Error);
                }

                if (ExchangeBrokerAccounts.HasError())
                {
                    error.AppendLine("ExchangeBrokerAccounts contains validation error(s).");
                }

            }

            return error.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging and verified that item.getProperties actually returns anything?

Comment: *"2 of the tables aren't getting any columns set or an empty row."* -- please provide some class definitions so we can find out for ourselves which two tables and why. "My code exhibits this vaguely defined behavior on input I won't tell you about" isn't any basis for diagnosing your problem.

Comment: FWIW I tested your code with made-up classes that all have one inherited property from a common base class, and one property of their own. It's working fine. So the problem is indeed something you haven't shown us.

Comment: @user3532232 I've debugged the item.getProperties, each of the objects that isn't working does have properties.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've added the class definitions.

Comment: I had to chop those up a bit to make them compile without all the dependencies, but I got all the columns. You're going to have to give this thing just one of the classes that have the issue, and step through ToDataSet() in the debugger. Pick one missing property. Does it come back from `GetProperties()`? Does `colType` make sense for that one?
 Follow that one case through the code until you see what happens with it. That's all I could do if I had code to reproduce the issue. And I'd find it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett  It's a strange issue. After stripping out the other classes and debugging the one's that weren't working, all properties look right.  Now I'm going to start stripping out the properties themselves to see which work.  Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: just a thougt: do you set the data type or the columns? I'd guess if the datat type is an int I doubt that you can add a DBNull.value?